# What is the wrong with this onPostexecute method in Asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

```
public class ShopsList extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView listView;
private StoreListAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<Stores> stores;
public static final String LOG_TAG = ShopsList.class.getName();
private String sampleURL = "http://104.199.230.125/stores/1.json/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shops_list);
    StoresAsyncTask task = new StoresAsyncTask();

    task.execute(sampleURL);

    mAdapter = new StoreListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, stores);
    listView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.store_list);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new       LinearLayoutManager(this);
    listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        private class StoresAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Stores>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Stores> doInBackground(String... URLs) {


        if (URLs.length < 1 || URLs[0] == null) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "URL is is null");
            return null;
        }
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "URL is not null" + URLs[0]);

        return QueryHandler.fetchStoreData(URLs[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Stores> data) {

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(data);
    }
}


}
```

it doesn't display the list, it just displays an empty list. I am using recyclerview.adapter. There is also this problem that getItemCount() throws nullpointer exception when [return this.stores.size();] is used and the app doesn't open, when i change this line to [return this.stores == null ? 0 : stores.size();] it opens but with empty list.

```
public int getItemCount() {

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stores size");
//       return this.stores.size();
    return this.stores == null ? 0 : stores.size();
}
```

when i use List view the postexecute method body is this, and it works.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Quakes> data) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }
```

how to correctly execute postexecute method in Asynctask that is related to recyclerview.adapter?
The JSON parsing is error free, only i am unable to load it into the adapter.

This is the adapter

public class StoreListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<Stores> stores = new ArrayList<>();
private int itemResource;
private Context context;

public StoreListAdapter(Context context, int itemResource, ArrayList<Stores> stores) {

    this.stores = stores;
    this.itemResource = itemResource;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public storeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);

    return new storeViewHolder(this.context, view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(storeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Stores stores = this.stores.get(position);
    holder.bindStoreData(stores);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stores size");
   return this.stores.size();
}}
```

Comment: i think you forgot to put mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: please see the first code onPostExecute method, is it not where mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged(); goes?
Note : the last code onPostExecute method is working fine which is related to List view. the above code onPostExecute method related to recyclerview is not working.
please suggest any changes there.

Comment: @P.Vamsi try commenting  listView.setAdapter(mAdapter); before Asynctask

Comment: Issue is with setting new data to adapter and making a refresh with notifyDataSetChange, check answer given by readyandroid

Comment: I tried but it is still the same, i think i have errors in the adapter.
can you please check the adapter if it is correct, it throws nullpointer exception at return this.stores.size();
when i replace it with return this.stores == null ? 0 : stores.size(); or return 0; the list is empty,
when i replace with return 1, it throws nullpointer exception at bindviewholders [Stores stores = this.stores.get(position);] line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get code in onPostExecute, you should pass this data in List Adapter

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Stores> data) {
        mAdapter = new StoreListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, data);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(data);
    }
```

Other way,i think better, if you are making custom list adapter make getter and setter or method like addAll to update data in list adapter.

**After edited**
Create getter and setter of `ArrayList<Stores> stores` and then

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Stores> data) {
            mAdapter.setStores(data);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Also in shopList class `private ArrayList<Stores> stores=  = new ArrayList<>();` may avoid null exception

Comment: the adapter is throwing nullpointer at getItemcount and bindviewholder.

i am using custom adapter uploaded above, how to update data in the method.

Comment: Wow, thanks man. the last line "Also in shopList class private ArrayList<Stores> stores=  = new ArrayList<>(); may avoid null exception" of yours did the trick.
I upvoted your answer but it says it doesn't count since i have <15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You had given answer of your own question programmatically:

Solution 1 from you:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Stores> data) {

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(data);
    }
```

Solution 2 from you:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Quakes> data) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }
```

In solution 1, you are adding adapter to listview again but doing updating list data to adapter. So this is the mistake you are making here, which is reolved in solution 2.

**Conclusion: There is no issue with onPostExecute. Problem is with passing updated data to adapter and making notifyDataDetChange to apply updated data to listview.**

So add the data to adapter by creating custome method like you had done with mAdapter.addAll(data/*new data*/) and then do notifyDataSetChange() to get refresh newly updated data with listview.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Quakes> data) {
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(data);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
        }
    }
```